# Trying to find volume by rotating a region..getting a negative value

Tags: integration, volume

I'm working on a review assignment for volumes of solids obtained by rotating a region bounded by given curves around a certain line (using washers or shells) and seem to be getting a negative answer for this one problem...

> Find volume of solid obtained by rotating region formed by x-y=3 and
>   $y^2 = x-1$ about the line $y=-2$

I tried to solve using washers with large radius $y^2+3$ and small radius y+5.

I end up trying to solve the following integral, and get $\frac{-207\pi}{5}$ , which I don't believe is the correct answer since it is negative..

$$\pi\int\limits_{-1}^{2} (y^2+3)^2-(y+5)^2 \, dy$$

Points of intersection are at $(2,-1)$ and $(5,2)$.

Any advice on what is going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The integral $\int (\cdots y \cdots) \,dx$ does not make sense -- the variable of integration is not what appears in the integrand.

Comment: If you're using washers for rotation around a _horizontal_ line you need to express $y$ as a function of $x$, not the other way around.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Oops, fixed the typo to 'dy' now. What would be my limits of integration if I write in terms of x? From the vertex to rightmost point? Or from POIntersection1 to POIntersection2?

Comment: x @m179: I repeat: If you're using washers for rotation around a _horizontal_ line, your integration variable should be $x$, and the integrand should express $y$-coordinates of boundary points as a function of their $x$ coodinates. It will not do, as you have done, to attempt to express the $x$ coordinates as a function of $y$ coordinates. That doesn't give you the right washer size -- a washer _is simply not identified_ by a particular $y$ coordinate. Instead there is a washer for each $x$ coordinate, so $x$ **must** be the variable you integrate over.

Comment: I strongly recommend using cylindrical shells instead of washers for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let us have a look at the region. The blue line is $y=-2$, and the region is clearly visible.

[image]

So we will have $x$ ranging over $1$ and the $x$ of the rightmost intersection of the curves. Let us find the intersections: $x-y=3$ or $y=x-3$, so subbing into $y^2=x-1$ we get $(x-3)^2=x-1$, or $x^2-6x+9=x-1$, or $x^2-7x+10=0$, which yields $x=\frac{7\pm\sqrt{49-40}}{2}=\frac{7\pm3}{2}$, which means $2$ and $5$. So $x\in[1,5]$. What about $y$? $y$ will range from $\max\{-\sqrt{x-1},x-3\}$ to $\sqrt{x-1}$. As can be seen from the picture, the maximum in question is $-\sqrt{x-1}$ from $1$ to the $2$, and $x-3$ from there on.

Since we are rotating about $y=-2$, we should consider $y+2$ instead of $y$. So for $x\in[1,2]$, $y+2\in[2-\sqrt{x-1},2+\sqrt{x+1}]$, while for $x\in[2,5]$, $y+2\in[x-1,2+\sqrt{x-1}]$.

To compute the volume of the solid obtained by rotating, we have to integrate the areas of the circular coronas that compose it. Breaking this into the two regions where the left extreme of $y$ has an analytical expression not involving a $\max$, we should get that our volume $V$ is:

$$V=\int\limits_1^2\pi((2+\sqrt{x-1})^2-(2-\sqrt{x-1})^2)\mathrm{d}x+\int\limits_2^5\pi((2+\sqrt{x-1})^2-(x-1)^2)\mathrm{d}x.$$

I guess you can take it from here.

For the curious, Wolfram ([1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+pi*%28%282%2Bsqrt%28x-1%29%29%5E2-%282-sqrt%28x-1%29%29%5E2%29dx+from+1+to+2) and [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+pi*%28%282%2Bsqrt%28x-1%29%29%5E2-%28x-1%29%5E2%29dx+from+2+to+5)) evaluates the two bits as:

$$V=\frac{16}{3}\pi+\frac{103}{3}\pi=\frac{16+103}{3}\pi=\frac{119}{3}\pi.$$

Comment: Wouldn't the point of intersection be at x=5 and x=2? I think there's a calculation error in the discriminant (should be 49-40). So what you're saying is I have to break this region up into 2 smaller regions essentially then?

Comment: Absolutely right :).

Comment: Just fixed @m179.

Comment: is there any reason why the x-1 term isn't squared in the second integral ? Other than that I understand the solution perfectly, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome and no, I made a mistake :).

Comment: Fixed. A typo that propagated into a full-fledged error on the Wolfram query :). One thing: I'd like to point out how much difference two dollars can make. `x-1` gives "x-1", while `$x-1$` gives "$x-1$". I'm sure we will agree on which one looks best :).